# Excel Programming for auto-complete of partial input (numbers)

Tags: excel, vba

We manage our inventories in Excel. I know its little old fashioned but we are developing business firm, and we have all our money blocked in business and no money to invest in IT.

So I wanted to know can I program in a way that excel automatically completes the product numbers?

This is example of one product category
[image: Example]

All our design codes are of 6 digits, What I really want is that when only partial number is added and hit enter it automatically completes the remaining digits by taking the above numbers.

So for example in this case what I am expecting is, if I type `5` hit enter it automatically makes it `790705` based on above number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following VBA code to the code section of your worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oldText  As String, aboveText As String, newText As String
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row >= 3 And Target.Text <> "" Then
        oldText = Target.Text
        aboveText = Target.Cells(0, 1).Text
        If Len(aboveText) = 6 And Len(oldText) < 6 Then
            newText = Left(aboveText, 6 - Len(oldText)) & oldText
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = newText
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

(change the column number and minimum row number above according to the actual column/row numbers in your worksheet).

Comment: Thank You very very very much.It will save a lot of time while adding stock

Comment: Nice.  I edited to disable events otherwise it gets called twice.

Comment: @Dick: thanks for the edit, should have added that by my own. I knew that the event was called twice, but ignored it since the test Len(oldText)<6 prevented the routine from infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
   If (Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 2 And Target.Value < 10) Then
       Target = Target.Offset(rowOffset:=-1) + 1
   End If
End Sub
```

As far as you enter a single digit in the new row, it transforms to the previous row + 1.